# How to change the page after POST in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What I'm trying to is they put the username and password and after they do that I check it and if its good then I change the page if not it alerts them its not right and doesn't change page.

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("LoginButton", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "LoginForm" }))
{
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </p>
}
```

Here's the controller I want to return something that makes the page change if that's possible.

```
public IActionResult LoginButton(string username,string password)
        {
            if (//Check username and password)
            {
                return // should change page "Controller/Page_i_want";
            }
            else
            {
                return //Not right password or username;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Make a new Blazor app, and tick the box saying you want an identity provider. Bang! The job is done

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. So if you just want to change the view you can do this

```
       if (//Check username and password)
            {
         return View("NameofView");   //ViewName
            }
            else
            {
              ViewBag.Error= "Not valid username";  
            }
```

Check this page for more info

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/writing-a-sample-login-page-in-asp-net-mvc/